# Wrapping WCF asynchronous call inside task.Factory.FromAsync doesn't return any result

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, task-parallel-library

I  have WCF service which has been called inside threadpool. The performance is really slow. So thought of replacing it with Task.Factory.FromAsync. But its not returning any result. I am calling this code from Silverlight client. When I debug the code it just returns exception "**The remote server returned an error: NotFound**" at call back method. The Fidler catches the exception as "**an error occurred when verifying security for the message**"

The code without any issues, but having performance is too low.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            AsyncCallback onEndGetItemProperty = (ar) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // complete get-item-properties async call
                    topologyItem.ItemProperties = configurationServiceChannel.EndGetItemProperty(ar);
                }
                finally
                {
                    configurationServiceChannel.Close();
                    combineCallback.Decrement();
                }
            };

            // begin get-items-properties async call
            Shell.WSOperation(() =>
                configurationServiceChannel.BeginGetItemProperty(itemId, topologyItem.GetPropertyQueries(), onEndGetItemProperty, configurationServiceChannel),
                configurationServiceChannel);
        });
```

I have replaced Threadpool with Async.

```
 Action<IAsyncResult> onEndGetItemProperty = (ar) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // complete get-item-properties async call
                    topologyItem.ItemProperties = configurationServiceChannel.EndGetItemProperty(ar);
                }
                finally
                {
                    configurationServiceChannel.Close();
                    combineCallback.Decrement();
                }
            };

            // begin get-items-properties async call

           await Task.Factory.FromAsync(configurationServiceChannel.BeginGetItemProperty(itemId, topologyItem.GetPropertyQueries(), null, configurationServiceChannel), onEndGetItemProperty);
```

Please let me know What I am missing here. The wcf configuration and security are perfect and no issues with it. I am not getting result only after changing it to Async.

Proxy:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true, Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/topology/IConfigurationServi" +
        "ce/GetItemProperty", ReplyAction = "http://schemas.microsoft.com//topology/IConfigurationServi" +
        "ce/GetItemPropertyResponse")]
    System.IAsyncResult BeginGetItemProperty(TopologyService.ItemId itemId, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TopologyService.ItemPropertyQuery> itemPropertyCriteria, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TopologyService.ItemProperty> EndGetItemProperty(System.IAsyncResult result);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Turn on WCF tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) to see what's happening

Comment: @Umesh, show the generated WCF proxy `BeginXXX/EndXXX` method signatures for `GetItemProperty`.

Comment: I enabled WCF tracing and I could see below error in traces. " Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security."

Comment: The proxy of the service are added

Comment: Calling a service asynchronously does not makes the service go faster. The service has no idea that it is being called like that. The question is probably moot.

Comment: @usr, perhaps the OP refers to the client side when he mentions the poor performance. Calling the WCF from a web application, perhaps?

Comment: @Noseratio still not sure why it would be any faster.

Comment: @usr, not really faster, just scale better - for the web app which calls this WCF. Which eventually, would serve end users "faster", if the web app is under a heavy load.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static class WcfExt
{
    public static Task<ObservableCollection<TopologyService.ItemProperty>>
        GetItemPropertyAsync(this ConfigurationService @this,
            TopologyService.ItemId itemId,
            ObservableCollection<TopologyService.ItemPropertQuery> itemPropertyCriteria)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            (asyncCallback, asyncState) =>
                @this.BeginGetItemProperty(
                    itemId, itemPropertyCriteria, 
                    asyncCallback, asyncState),
            (asyncResult) =>
                @this.EndGetItemProperty(asyncResult), null);
    }
}

// ... 
// calling it
try 
{           
    topologyItem.ItemProperties = await configurationServiceChannel.GetItemPropertyAsync(
        itemId, itemPropertyCriteria);
}
finally
{
    configurationServiceChannel.Close();
}
```

Comment: That FromAsync call looks a lot saner. Another option would be to generate a proxy that supports the TAP pattern.